# How to pass several variables of different types from one function to another on android?

Tags: android, android-maps

I have getFilmsBrowse function and it should return the following field:

- name (String)
- description (String)
- year (Int)
- etc.

Results of this function to be used in another function displayMovies.
How can I pass them and be able to use names of fields in displayMovies?
Wanted to use `Map` for the same, but it is not clear for me how to initialize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Bundle` class for this. It's like a `Map`, but it can contain values of different types.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a collection, but why not create a class called Film, with private member variables called name, description, year etc, and then accessor methods like getYear(). Then you can do this:

```
Film film = getFilmsBrowse(...);
int year = film.getYear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create some model classes which will hold data:

```
public class Page implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    //and so on...
    public Page(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Now you can create a `Page` object and fill it with data(name, description) via the constructor.  Optionally make some setters.

```
Page p = new Page("James", "Hello World");
startActivity(new Intent(context, MyActivity.class).putExtra("Page", p));
```

Retrieve your `Page` in `MyActivity` in its `onCreate` method:

```
Page p = (Page)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Page");
Toast.makeText(this, "Name: " + p.getName() + ", Description:" + p.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving from Activity to Activity you will use Intents and Bundle to pass parameters. If you're calling a function and reutrning to your original activity, then you will use conventional java