# Saving data from activity(A) and reading in another Activity(history)

Tags: android

I have an activity that contain a list of data (TextView), i need to save this data that have been choose (onClick) in the list and been able to get and read it in another activity(history)

I understand that is exist a possibility with the "serializable"  but i did not success to understand how it could help me.

i will be happy if someone can clarify this subject for me,example?.

Thank you for helping!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to pass a `String` to another activity, you can do this with `putExtra` and `getStringExtra`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("parameter", myStringParameter);
startActivity(intent);
```

and then read it in `OtherActivity`'s `onCreate` method:

```
String parameter = getIntent().getStringExtra("parameter");
```

The `Serializable` interface is useful for marshalling more complicated objects; you don't need this if you're just dealing with `String`.

**Edit** - if you need to store small amounts of data persistently you could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

```
final String TAG = "MyApplication";
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("parameter", myStringParameter).commit();
```

and then to read the preferences:

```
final String TAG = "MyApplication";
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
String parameter = prefs.getString("parameter", null);
```

This data will be available even after your application closes.

Comment: Its not good for me because i need to save the data even when the app is close.

Comment: I added the `SharedPreferences` method which allows you to store data persistently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use classes that implement `Serializable`.  See my answer on this question: [How to pass several variables of different types from one function to another on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437433/how-to-pass-several-variables-of-different-types-from-one-function-to-another-on/5437535#5437535)

Create some model classes which will hold data:

```
public class Page implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    //and so on...
    public Page(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Now you can create a `Page` object and fill it with data(name, description) via the constructor.  Optionally make some setters.

```
Page p = new Page("James", "Hello World");
startActivity(new Intent(context, MyActivity.class).putExtra("Page", p));
```

Retrieve your `Page` in `MyActivity` in its `onCreate` method:

```
Page p = (Page)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Page");
Toast.makeText(this, "Name: " + p.getName() + ", Description:" + p.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending immutable stateful objects between activities (messaging) is commendable, IMHO. It can be argued that OOP is about messaging, not objects. Two suggestions. 1) use the fully qualified name for the name:value pair so do:

```
private void launchManagePassword() {
    Intent i= new Intent(this, ManagePassword.class); // no param constructor
    PasswordState outState= new PasswordState(lengthKey,timeExpire,isValidKey,timeoutType,"",model.getIsHashPassword());
    Bundle b= new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("jalcomputing.confusetext.PasswordState", outState);
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_MANAGE_PASSWORD); // used for callback
}
```

This will minimize runtime casting errors.

2) When you have the app working well and the object interface is *stabilized* consider refactoring the code to a Parcel for speed.

JAL

EDIT: AS REQUESTED [Code](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/saving-instance-state)

Comment: I don't really understand you solution,can you bring an example

Comment: @dirko I added a link to my answer. It may be MORE than what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

I am aware about the methods mentioned above. But just for alternative thoughts, since you are mentioning the history word, how about using SQLite for this purpose? 
In first activity, you can save the data, and in second activity, retrieve the data.

Comment: Hi,You right it is solution but i would like to know the "Serializable".

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between your activities in various ways depending on how much data you need to save and how long the data needs to be saved.

1. **Intents** : Useful when transferring small bits of data between 2-3 screens
2. **Singleton / Static data store classes** : useful when sharing lot of data between various activities
3. **SQLite DB** : Large amount of data to be shared , also useful to save the same between app launches
4. **Shared Preferences** : Small amount of data , between app launches.

For your use-case its best to use intents unless the data is shared between more than 2-3 activities where option 2 would be a better solution